# OSX bash. grep for string "--version="

Tags: bash, grep, osx

How can I search for string `--version=` using grep in OSX bash?

When I try something like this:

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir=out "--version=" .
```

I get

```
grep: option `--version' doesn't allow an argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir=out -- "--version=" .
```

grep 'see' `--version` as a switch, so there's need to say : *end of arguments* with `--`

Answer (score 1):

Canonical answer for this is:

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir=out -e "--version=" .
```

Of course, using the argument separator `--` will also work, but `-e` is specifically the option to use when specifying an arbitrary pattern. Or several, you can do:

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir=out -e "--version=" -e "--version " .
```

Comment: `--` is more generic: work for all commands, not only grep

Comment: Right, but not the point there: `--` is the POSIX argument separator. `-e` is the grep option to take a pattern. That grep also takes a pattern as argument is “accident”. Both answers were valid. I actually upvoted your answer, but wanted to share the canonical answer for grep – from all code I normally see, nobody uses `--` for a grep pattern, everyone uses `-e`, and that’s what “canonical” means.